# PHPUnit withConsecutive strange behaviour

Tags: php, object, phpunit

Consider the next test:

```php
class User
{
}

class UserRepository
{
    public function getByName($name)
    {
    }

    public function getByUser(User $user)
    {
    }
}

class UserController
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function findByNames($name1, $name2)
    {
        $this->userRepository->getByName($name1);
        $this->userRepository->getByName($name2);
    }

    public function findByUsers($user1, $user2)
    {
        $this->userRepository->getByUser($user1);
        $this->userRepository->getByUser($user2);
    }
}

class WithConsecutiveTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * This test is fails if some of "Alice" or "Bob" string changed. This is expected behaviour.
     */
    public function testWithConsecutiveOnStrings()
    {
        $name1 = 'Alice';
        $name2 = 'Bob';

        $userRepository = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);

        $userRepository
            ->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('getByName')
            ->withConsecutive(
                [$name1], // change to $name2 and test fails
                [$name2]
            );

        $userController = new UserController($userRepository);
        $userController->findByNames($name1, $name2);
    }

    /**
     * This test is NOT fails if in "withConsecutive()" call $user1 changed to $user2. This is unexpected behaviour.
     */
    public function testWithConsecutiveOnObjects()
    {
        $user1 = $this->createMock(User::class);
        $user2 = $this->createMock(User::class);

        $this->assertEquals($user1, $user2);
        $this->assertNotSame($user1, $user2);

        $userRepository = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);

        $userRepository
            ->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('getByUser')
            ->withConsecutive(
                [$user1], // change to $user2 and test is also passed
                [$user2]
            );

        $userController = new UserController($userRepository);
        $userController->findByUsers($user1, $user2);
    }
}
```

First test with string arguments for "withConsecutive()" is works correctly, but second test with objects do some magic: something similar to weak comparison of two objects is here, so second test is passed in any case.

I tried with "[$this->callback(function($user1arg) use ($user1)){return $user1arg === $user1}]" constraint - this works well, but write a lot of this constraint is a some kind of monkey job.

Maybe it may have a more simple solution, instead of writing a lot of constraints with $this->callback(...) for objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything in PHPUnit is perfect, but this should work for You. Of course property 'name' is only an example. If user does not holds any behaviour, You don't need to mock it.

```
class User
{
    private $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName($name)
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

test method

```
public function testWithConsecutiveOnObjects()
{
    $user1 = new User();
    $user1->setName('Alice');
    $user2 = new User();
    $user2->setName('Bob');
    $this->assertNotEquals($user1, $user2);
    $this->assertNotSame($user1, $user2);
    $userRepository = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);
    $userRepository
        ->expects($this->exactly(2))
        ->method('getByUser')
        ->withConsecutive(
            [$user1], //we are comparing values here, not references
            [$user2]
        );
    $userController = new UserController($userRepository);
    $userController->findByUsers($user1, $user2);
}
```

Comment: Looks like an ugly hack :) Working, but very strange solution: makes the test code more complicated for understanding for other developers.

Comment: As I explained  in comment, you need to make objects to have different values. This assertion is comparing values, not references.

Comment: Oh, so, PHPUnit dont have an assertion, that compare references?

Comment: It has, but not in `->withConsecutive(...)` case - here we are checking only values. `assertSame(...)` is asserting on values AND types/references. `assertEquals(...)` is asserting only values

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 $userRepository
     ->expects($this->exactly(2))
     ->method('getByUser')
     ->withConsecutive(
         [$this->identicalTo($user1)],
         [$this->identicalTo($user2)]
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `->withConsecutive()` method is removed in newer PHPUnit Versions.

You can see how this repository is using it (or use it directly): https://github.com/nopenopenope/phpunit-consecutive-params

In general, a trait is used to make use of the withConsecutive logic like before. When using the module above, all calls go from `->withConsecutive([...])` to `->with(...$this->withConsecutive([...]))`.